# PyCharm Git VCS Greys Out Add option

Tags: python-3.x, github, version-control, pycharm

I am using PyCharm's VCS options to synchronize a project between different computers.

On a slave computer I downloaded the repository and changes to the .py code is working without any problems.

There is a directory that contains within it an XL file. This file was downloaded during the initial pull but updates to it are not being detected (and therefore being pushed).

[The screen shot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnb6x.png) shows the shortcut menu I see when I right click on this file.  The + Add option is greyed out.

I can confirm that if I do this from the GitHub web interface it works without problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it listed in `Git -  Commit` after changes have been done?

Comment: @user2235698: No it is not. Is there a way I can add it.  A solution ***might*** be to wipe the repository and download it again but I feel that would beat the scope of having a shared repository